# Wine 1.3.25 update broke sound, how do I go back?

Tags: sound, wine, updates

Last Friday's Wine update to 1.3.25 broke sound, how do I go back to the previous version of Wine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are instructions [here](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu), on WineHQ. You need to uninstall and reinstall an earlier version. According to the FAQ, [this won't uninstall your apps.](http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#uninstall_app)

It's more likely to be a problem with your configuration or a sound driver, though. You should open up the Wine configuration to be sure.

If the problem is not fixed when you use an older version of Wine, try 1) changing your sound driver to each individual sound driver and no other, then 2) removing your .wine directory and reinstalling your apps.

Comment: Nothing to do with configuration, broken sound widely reported with upgrade.

Comment: I also suggested it for the case that the upgrade somehow changed or required a different configuration. I'm not familiar with this particular upgrade, but I've dealt with Wine a lot before.

Comment: I backed up my wine prefix folder; used Synaptic to remove anything wine; and then installed 1.3.24.  My sound seems to be fine now.  I did not need my backup.  Applications and configurations are as they were before.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can get older versions of Wine for Ubuntu(in .deb format): http://wine.budgetdedicated.com/archive/binary/

Answer (score 1):

I see Kevin already got his earlier version but others might come to get answers so I'll post what worked for me :)  This doesn't help you to revert to an earlier version of Wine, but it might enable sound in the current version.  I also had no sound in wine after updating.  On the audio tab of winecfg the audio test failed.  I am using wine 1.3.28

The sound driver may not be set correctly in wines registry.  You can set it to alsa by

From the terminal use `wine regedit`

Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\Drivers`

Open the Audio key and type `Alsa`

I hope this helps some!